# Alternative browsers for iPod touch?

Tags: browser, safari, ipod, ipod-touch

So now that I've gotten more comfortable with this iPod touch I think I need a better browser. Is there anything else besides Safari?

Comment: Some websites have problems opening up. Some javascript errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am afaraid that there are actually none that would help you. You see, all of the [alternative browsers](http://www.macworld.com/appguide/article.html?article=138409) that are available for the iPhone and iPod touch are all based on the same Webkit foundation as Safari. This means that they will all have the same disadvantages (and advantages) when it comes to rendering websites as Mobile Safari.

It would be a long time before you see something like Firefox (Fennec?) on the iPhone, mainly because of the Apple SDK restrictions.

Answer (score 2):

No. See [here](http://forums.macrumors.com/showthread.php?t=556809)

Apple doesn't allow them, because they will too closely mirror built in apps. Apple doesn't like competition.